# How are primes produced just by adding a constant number? And how are primes in each column consecutive?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was working with prime numbers. I used a positive even number ($30$) to add to the prime numbers to make another prime numbers. I started from $7$ because it is the smallest prime number that makes another prime number when added to $30$:

[image: Primes]

As you can see $7,11,13,17$ are consecutive prime numbers. Also, $37,41,43,47$ are consecutive. And so on. Also, the picture has four rows.

Is this an established property? How can a positive even number produce other prime numbers that are consecutive in each column?I know from my works that the minimum even number that works is $4$ which produces one row. But is there also a maximum even number that can uphold this property?

Comment: Is *what* an established property?  Clearly, if $p>q$ are two odd primes, then $p-q$ is an even integer.  And Dirichlet tells us (loosely) that there are infinitely many primes with the same remainder modulo any divisor.  What property are you after here?

Comment: Should stress:  you are working with very small natural numbers so if you exclude $2,3, 5$ as divisors, you are going to get a whole lot of primes.  That doesn't mean much.

Comment: Plesae write an *informative* title... one that relates to the specifics of the content.

Comment: @lulu The property that prime numbers are consecutive in each column.

Comment: I don't understand.  You chose $7,11,13,17$ precisely because they were consecutive, right?

Comment: @lulu And adding a constant number to any of them produces other consecutive primes. And adding the same number to the produced primes again produces consecutive primes. This is strange to me. So primes have a pattern

Comment: I think you are just looking at small numbers here.  The only two digit composites without $2,3,5$ as a factor are $49, 77, 91$.    From that you might get the sense that there are very few such numbers, but of course there are lots and lots.  Many "patterns" appear to be true if you only look at small numbers.  Try large ones.

Comment: @lulu I used $210$ too (from the answer) and it worked. The numbers were big but it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so strange. The numbers $6 = 2 \times 3$ and $30 = 2 \times 3 \times 5$ are the products of the first few primes. See what happens when you try your experiment with the next such number, $210 = 7 \times 30$.

Comment: Also, the total number of primes in my experiment is a prime number itself!